# How do I reverse a string by character instead of flipping the whole string?

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

If the string is "hello world", 
I need to flip every pair of characters and return "ehll oowlrd". 
The way I do it returns "olleh dlrow".

```
var flipPairs = function (string) {

  return string.split("").reverse().join("");

}
```

console.log(flipPairs("hello world"));
// -> ehll oowlrd

Comment: please add your try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression - match two consecutive characters, and replace with them in reversed order:

```js
const flipPairs = str => str.replace(/(.)(.)/g, '$2$1');

console.log(flipPairs("hello world"));
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```js
function flip(s)
{
    let r = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i+=2)
        r += (i+1 < s.length ? s[i+1] : "")+s[i];
    return r;
}
console.log(flip("hello world"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the index and take this character of the actual one if the string has an odd length.

```js
function flipPairs(string) {
    return [...string].map((c, i, a) => a[i + ((i + 1) % 2 || -1)] || c).join('');
}

console.log(flipPairs('hello world'));
```